# php generated option selected by default

Tags: php, forms, selected

I'm probably blind to my own mistake again, but why doesn't 2011 become the default selected year? (The -- are for debugging, they show up that the if statement works correctly.)

```
for($year=1900;$year<=2050;$year++) {
 if ($year==date("Y"))
   echo "<option value='".$year."' selected='selected'>--".$year."</option>";
 else
   echo "<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>";
}
```

The selected='selected' should just work. ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_selected.asp)) So it is either a stupid mistake(i really don't see one) or some effect from php..

**UPDATE**:
found the problem.. the ftp didn't overwrite the file properly. Now it works. Thanks for the fast help, when these things happen I always start doubting my own sanity. (cant send this as answer because i have a low rep)

Comment: It works here... What is your resulting HTML including select tags? (for a smaller range :P )

Comment: So does `selected='selected'` appear in the rendered HTML?

Comment: I think the correct is `selected` not `selected='selected'` but to get an correct answer post and the generated html

Comment: If you're using Firefox and do soft refreshes (e.g. `<F5>`), the browser may remember the previously selected value you had and keep it (while ignoring `selected="selected"`). To work around this "feature", use hard-refresh (`<Ctrl>+<F5>`)

Comment: `selected = "selected"` is ok for this. Pls Copy the generated HTML output from your browser and paste it here.

Comment: posting a question because you didn't upload the file on your production is not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking the generated HTML? Maybe this code works well (it seems it does), but the problem is in select, or in another place.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no effect on the browser behaviour, so if it doesn't work, it is a stupid mistake in the HTML output. ;)

Best thing is checking if the `selected` variant is actually outputted. Could be that the comparison evaluates to false, so it's always the second line. A little debugging should point out fast what is wrong. Check the output in the browser or var_dump the values of $year and date('Y') to see if they return what you expect.

At first sight I see no error here. Do you have any Javascript that might influence the selection?

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL + SHIFT + R` if you use firefox.
I had that problem very often too ..
It should be just the cache.

Btw.: You should rather use double quotes for html attributes. That's more "usual". :)